# Why does Windows Explorer show up in task manager as “explorer.EXE”?

Tags: windows-explorer, task-manager, filenames

I’ve been noticing that Windows Explorer’s file name in the Task Manager, ends with `.EXE` instead of `.exe`.

I decided to kill the process and restart Explorer. Now it shows up as `explorer.exe`, however it always defaults back to `explorer.EXE` when I restart my Toshiba Laptop running Windows 7 Pro.

Comment: Open a command-prompt (`cmd`) and type `where *explorer*.exe`. Is there more than one result? Do any end in `.EXE`?

Comment: Download Process Explorer, scroll to Explorer.EXE and check properties. It will give you the exact location of the exe. Post it here so that we can help you figure out if it is a rogue exe.

Comment: What version of Windows you running ?